Output of unique test reports not working
I configured Playwright to append new Date() to the test report folder which meant that each test run outputted a new test report which could be identified by the datetime in the title.
Recently reports have started over-writing each other - it seems as though a new instance of the reporter and report folder isn't being created with each run.
This used to work. This is the reporter config in the playwright.config.ts file:
  reporter: [
    [
      'html',
      {
        outputFolder: process.env.CI
          ? 'test-reports'
          : `test-reports/${new Date().toISOString()}`,
        open: 'never',
      },
    ],
  ],

